# How to update Span (Bokeh) using ColumnDataSource?

Tags: python, bokeh, pandas-bokeh

I am trying to update Span using ColumnDataSource, but the information is not being passed onto the source. Span unfortunately does not have a paremeter "source", so is there a better way?

I have defined my sources, figure and line like so:

```
m1_source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x1=[], y1=[]))
m1_spans = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x1=[]))    
p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", title="", sizing_mode="fixed", height = 500, width = 1400)
p.line(x ="x1", y="y1", color = 'blue', source=m1_source)
```

Then I have a for loop that should ideally plot multiple spans, each 'i' will be a separate timestamp:

```
for i in m1_spans.data['x1']:
    p.add_layout(Span(location=i, dimension='height', line_color='red', line_dash='solid', line_width=1))
```

This is taken from my update() function:

```
m1_source.data = dict(
   x1=machine_1_vals['mpTimestamp'],
   y1=machine_1_vals['Value'])

m1_spans.data = dict( x1=ToolsDF.loc[ToolsDF['Value'] == float(vals['Tool_val'])]['Timestamp'])
```

I have checked this, and m1_spans does successfully return multiple timestamps, so the error shouldn't be here.

The reason I am confused, is because my p.line will successfully update with no issues, but it does have a *source* parameter, while span does not.

I would be really appreciative for any advice about how to solve this issue.
If I should have supplied more information, I apologize and can update as needed, I just tried to keep it brief for you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Span` objects do not currently have an ability to be "powered" by a `ColumnDataSource`. Each `Span` only draws one span, specified by its own `location` property.

You will need to update the `location` property individually on each `Span` object in order to update it. Alternatively, if you absolutely want to be able to drive updates through a CDS, you could look at using a `multi_line`, `segment`, or `ray` glyph instead. Those all have different ways to configure their coordinates, so you'd have to see which is most convenient to your use-case. But they all come with  one trade-off, which is that none of them have the full "infinite extent" that a `Span` supports.

Comment: Thanks very much! The second time you've helped me out with Bokeh. MultiLine was the way to go :)